# How to find the specified field in spring-data-jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I want to find the specified field with the interface which extends JpaSpecificationExecutor.but i have not idea.
for example,i just need to find id,nickname in the user entity,what shall I do?

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    public Page<User> findAll(User user, Pageable pageable) {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (user != null) {
            //some condition
        }
        query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        return query.getRestriction();
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "sys_user")
public class Note implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nickname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer on your question: `https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections` .

Comment: thanks for your help,but that can only add fixed condition,i need a way to add dynamic condition ,like this:if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(user.getNickname())){root.get("nickname").like(user.getNickname)}